# how to git merge a fork

Tags: git, merge

I have a git source code repository with a structure something like this.

```
origin/master
    root\
    +--src\
       +--A\
       +--B\
       +--C\

upstream/master
    src\
    +--A\
    +--B\
    +--C\
```

I have made local modifications to `src/` and the owner of `src/` has made other changes in `upstream/master`. I want to update my local fork of `src/` with theirs.

I wanted to do a `git merge upstream/master` as detailed [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/). But that left me with a structure like this:

```
origin/master
root\
+--src\
|  +--A\
|  +--B\
|  +--C\
+--A\
+--B\
+--C\
```

So, I found [Subtree Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) but I get errors about files overlapping. (of course they overlap! I'm merging!)

```
E:\root>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

E:\root>git read-tree --prefix src/ -u upstream/master
error: Entry 'src/.gitattributes' overlaps with 'src/.gitattributes'.  Cannot bind.
```

What do I need to do to merge the upstream repository with my fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Git documentation for read-tree:

> Keep the current index contents, and read the contents of the named tree-ish under the directory at `<prefix>`. The command will refuse to overwrite entries that already existed in the original index file. Note that the `<prefix>/` value must end with a slash.

Basically, read-tree does not do merging. You need to do a merge. Try instead:

```
git merge upstream/master -s recursive -X subtree=src/
```